# Yii2: Is it possible to change the default name for the migration table?

Tags: php, yii2, migration, database-migration

By default Yii names the migration table `migration` but it is possible to change this default? Preferrably also without having to specify it in every single migration file...

Comment: Yes is possibile and there are several way .. the simplest in config ...i have posted an answer .. hope is useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In console/config/main.php  you can add the tablename you prefer in controllerMap eg:

```
  return [
      'id' => 'app-console',
      'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
      'bootstrap' => ['log'],
      'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
      ......
      'controllerMap' => [
          'migrate' => [
              'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
              'migrationTable' => 'your_migration_table',
          ],
      ],
      .....     
      'components' => [
```

from yii2 guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#customizing-migrations

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DI container for this.

Add the following to your config/console.php

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\console\controllers\MigrateController', [
   'migrationTable' => '{{%table_name}}'
]);
```